# Parallel construction/instantiation in c++

Tags: c++, c++17, stdthread, stdasync

I have a class that has many setter methods.

Each subsequent setter method requires the data that has been set by the preceding setter method. i.e. if `setA()` has set the variable `_a` in the class, then `setB()` will require the variable `_a`

If not initialised in the constructor's initialisation list, I would have to call the methods after the object has been instantiated.

I have a significant number of objects on which to call these methods. Thus, I would call the methods on those objects in parallel using `std::async()`.

The problem with calling `std::async(std::launch::async, &SomeClass::setB, std::ref(objectOfSomeClass))` is that it requires `_a` to have been already set by `setA()`. This may not be the case given the random order in which tasks are executed.

But, i figure it would be easier to invoke the setters in the initialisation list. i.e. `SomeClass() : _a(setA()), _b(setB()) {}` **and parallelise the construction instead.**

Is this thinking correct? Is there a better way to do it?

I think one alternative is to create a single method that invokes the setters(`void run() {this->_a = setA(); this->_b = setB();}`), and call that using `std::async()` in main.

**How can I construct objects using `std::async()` and then store them in a vector so that I can access data from the objects that i have created using tasks?**

Comment: *"create a single method that invokes the setters"* Sounds good, why not do that? A lambda would also work.

Comment: Okay thank you. But, is there a way to just parallelise the construction?

Comment: One thing to consider is that `std::async` will have to setup and start a thread. This *also* has some costs, which may or may not be larger than initializing a SomeClass object.

Comment: *"is there a way to just parallelise the construction"* Sure, pass a lambda that calls the constructor to `async`.

Comment: You should not try to parallelize the construction. You should parallelize the data acquisition and only then construct the object which should be fast and require no parallelization.